# Remove [Object] label in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm a newbie in highchart and not familiar with advance javascript functions and I have created a chart with custom x-axis value. Everything works fine but there's a label that annoyed me. There is an [object Object] label in a chart.

Comment: can't help without seeing your code.

Comment: Please recreate your example as live demo on the jsfiddle.net

Comment: This means that whatever you're parsing to create your labels, you are not getting back a string, but an object. The browser can't do anything with it, so it's telling you that what you're returning is an object. Show us what you're parsing and how. Use console.log(*yourValue*) to view the actual object being output in the console.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you

```
 xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            title: {
            text: ''
        },
    },
```

You can change the x-Axis label and also leave it blank if you want it empty.

See the following link for a working example

[Highcharts - basic line chart](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/)

If any specific help is required please share your src code with us.

Answer (score 0):

The chart looks like this:

```
100 |
 90 |
 80 |
 70 |
 60 |
 50 |
 40 |
 30 |
 20 |
 10 |
  0 -------------------------------------------------------------
    [Object     1:00    2:00   3:00   4:00  5:00
     Object]
```

Comment: Yes. See the comments above. We can't help you without seeing the code you're using to create your labels.